# Using getApplicationContext() in another simple class, NOT in MainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-context

I've created a simple class for my Android application called `coreTuts`. I'm done with tying it in to my `MainActivity.java`, `activity_main.xml`, and so on, like this:

**MainActivity.java**

```html
coreTuts tuts = new coreTuts();
 
public void displayToast(View view)
{
 tuts.sampleToast();
}
```

This is what my `coreTuts.java` looks like:

**coreTuts.java**

```html
public class coreTuts{

 
 //Do a toast notification
 public void sampleToast()
 {
  
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
          "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
      
  toast.show();
 }

}
```

I couldn't decide whether I should use`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`or just `getApplicationContext()` on my `Toast` because either code doesn't work.

In fact, these are my questions:

1. I understand contexts in Android are kinda like habitats to animals. Am I right if I look at `getActivity()` and `getApplicationContext()` that way?
2. How do I make `getApplicationContext()` work in another class so that I can run my `toast`, or is that even allowed?

Thank you!

Comment: you can pass Context instance as argument to the sampleToast() method like sampleToast(Context context)

Comment: I think there are tons of question for this problem. And all of them saying you need to pass in a Context object to the class in order to get it. For example, sampleToast(Context context){...makeText(context, ....)}

Comment: I've viewed the first three answers, and it seems that my app's Context always gets its value from MainActivity.java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your coreTuts should be like below

```
public class coreTuts{


//Do a toast notification
public void sampleToast(Context context)
{

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
            "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    toast.show();
}

}
```

and you can invoke it like below,

```
coreTuts tuts = new coreTuts();

public void displayToast(View view)
{
   tuts.sampleToast(view.getContext());
}
```

Note: view cannot be null

Comment: I have two follow-up questions: Should I always remember that in `MainActivity.java`, all my methods that will display content on my app should always have that `View view` argument inside? And in `sampleToast()`, can `Context context` be placed anywhere else inside the method? :)

Comment: @MonicaLabbao you are welcome. 1) You need not have that view argument inside. you can use MainActivity.this for that(i mean whenever you need a context).  2) i think by anywhere you meant that you can pass it as second argument or third argument also. yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

As your class `CoreTuts` is not inheriting from `Activity` nor any other `Context` subclass ([Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) is a child of `Context`) you can't access to your context the way you are trying to. You need to explicitly pass it to your `sampleToast` method, like this:

```
public class coreTuts{

    //Do a toast notification
    public void sampleToast(Context context) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,
                "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

And in your activity:

```
coreTuts tuts = new coreTuts();

public void displayToast(View view) {
    // Pass your activity as the context
    tuts.sampleToast(this);
}
```

Comment: Got it, gotta write the `Context context` argument inside the method when my class coreTuts is not inheriting anything from Activity or Context's sublclasses. Would you advise this method of putting `Context context` as arguments to my method if I wouldn't use it for anything else? :)

Comment: Yes! If you are not going to use the `Context` for anything else there's no need to hold a reference to it (actually it is more complicated than it seems because of your activity's lifecycle). This way you use it just when you need it.

Comment: If you want to know more about holding a reference to context, you can start taking a look at [this](http://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/).

Comment: Thank you @peguerosdc! That reference sure satisfied my first impressions! :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass a context to your coretuts class when you're creating it's object. Your coretuts class would look like this.

```
public class coreTuts{

private Context mContext;

public coreTuts(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

//Do a toast notification
public void sampleToast()
{

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext,
            "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

    toast.show();
}

}
```

Now, when you're creating an object of this class inside your MainActivity, simply pass the context

```
// Pass your context. You can also use getApplicationContext() instead of MainActivity.this
coreTuts tuts = new coreTuts(MainActivity.this);

// You don't really need a view argument for this method. 
// It could just be public void displayToast() {...}
public void displayToast(View view)
{
    tuts.sampleToast();
}
```